Matplotlib: wrong positions of the cursors on a graph
In the program below, I want to place 2 vertical cursors at 2 defined positions on the ais x. The problem is that, as you can see in the screenshot, the cursors do not match the values chosen in the fields "curseur 1" et "curseur 2."
Moreover, the values of the x axis (the scale), disappear when the cursors are placed. And when the cursors are removed, by deselecting the button "Curseurs," the values of the cursor stay on the axis x...
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog,messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
from matplotlib.backend_bases import MouseButton
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg,NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.widgets import Button,CheckButtons,Slider,Cursor

def gestion_curseurs(event):
    global fenetre,fenetre_ouverte,largeur_fenetre,longueur_fenetre,bouton_curseurs,decision_curseurs,label_alerte_curseurs,saisie_curseur_1,variable_curseur_1,saisie_curseur_2,variable_curseur_2,bouton_valider_curseurs
    if fenetre_ouverte=="non":
        fenetre=tk.Tk()
        fenetre.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",valider_curseurs)
        fenetre.title("Gestion des curseurs")
        fenetre.resizable(width=False,height=False)
        fenetre["bg"]="black"
        fenetre_ouverte="oui"
        label_curseurs=Label(fenetre,text="GESTION DES CURSEURS",bg="black",fg="white",font=25)
        label_curseurs.place(x=0,y=0)
        decision_curseurs=tk.BooleanVar(master=fenetre)
        bouton_curseurs=tk.Checkbutton(fenetre,text="Curseurs",bg="white",fg="black",font=25,variable=decision_curseurs,onvalue=True,offvalue=False)
        bouton_curseurs.place(x=0,y=label_curseurs.winfo_reqheight()+25)
        if valeur_curseur_1!="":bouton_curseurs.select()
        label_alerte_curseurs=Label(fenetre,text="",bg="black",fg="red",font=25)
        label_curseur_1=Label(fenetre,text="Curseur 1 : ",bg="black",fg="blue",font=25)
        label_curseur_1.place(x=0,y=label_curseurs.winfo_reqheight()+25+bouton_curseurs.winfo_reqheight()+10)
        variable_curseur_1=tk.StringVar(master=fenetre)
        saisie_curseur_1=tk.Entry(fenetre,textvariable=variable_curseur_1,bg="white",fg="black",insertbackground="black",font=25,width=10)
        saisie_curseur_1.place(x=label_curseur_1.winfo_reqwidth(),y=label_curseurs.winfo_reqheight()+25+bouton_curseurs.winfo_reqheight()+10)
        variable_curseur_1.trace("w",lambda name,index,mode,variable_curseur_1=variable_curseur_1:entree_saisie_curseurs(variable_curseur_1))
        label_curseur_2=Label(fenetre,text="Curseur 2 : ",bg="black",fg="red",font=25)
        label_curseur_2.place(x=0,y=label_curseurs.winfo_reqheight()+25+bouton_curseurs.winfo_reqheight()+10+label_curseur_1.winfo_reqheight()+5)
        variable_curseur_2=tk.StringVar(master=fenetre)
        saisie_curseur_2=tk.Entry(fenetre,textvariable=variable_curseur_2,bg="white",fg="black",insertbackground="black",font=25,width=10)
        saisie_curseur_2.place(x=label_curseur_2.winfo_reqwidth(),y=label_curseurs.winfo_reqheight()+25+bouton_curseurs.winfo_reqheight()+10+label_curseur_1.winfo_reqheight()+5)
        variable_curseur_2.trace("w",lambda name,index,mode,variable_curseur_2=variable_curseur_2:entree_saisie_curseurs(variable_curseur_2))
        bouton_valider_curseurs=tk.Button(fenetre,text="\u2716 Terminer",bg="orange",fg="white",font=25,width=10,command=valider_curseurs)
        bouton_valider_curseurs.place(x=0,y=label_curseurs.winfo_reqheight()+25+bouton_curseurs.winfo_reqheight()+10+label_curseur_1.winfo_reqheight()+5+label_curseur_2.winfo_reqheight()+25)
        largeur_fenetre,longueur_fenetre=label_curseurs.winfo_reqheight()+25+bouton_curseurs.winfo_reqheight()+10+label_curseur_1.winfo_reqheight()+5+label_curseur_2.winfo_reqheight()+25+bouton_valider_curseurs.winfo_reqheight(),int(fenetre.winfo_screenheight()/720*500*1.2*1.5)
        fenetre.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(longueur_fenetre,largeur_fenetre,fenetre.winfo_screenwidth()//2-(longueur_fenetre+2*(fenetre.winfo_rootx()-fenetre.winfo_x()))//2,fenetre.winfo_screenheight()//2-(largeur_fenetre+fenetre.winfo_rooty()-fenetre.winfo_y()+fenetre.winfo_rootx()-fenetre.winfo_x())//2))
        variable_curseur_1.set(valeur_curseur_1),variable_curseur_2.set(valeur_curseur_2)
def entree_saisie_curseurs(variable_curseurs):
    if variable_curseur_1.get()!="":
        try:
            float(variable_curseur_1.get())
            erreur_curseur_1="non"
            saisie_curseur_1.configure(fg="black")
        except:
            erreur_curseur_1="oui"
            saisie_curseur_1.configure(fg="red")
    else:erreur_curseur_1="vide"
    if variable_curseur_2.get()!="":
        try:
            float(variable_curseur_2.get())
            erreur_curseur_2="non"
            saisie_curseur_2.configure(fg="black")
        except:
            erreur_curseur_2="oui"
            saisie_curseur_2.configure(fg="red")
    else:erreur_curseur_2="vide"
    if erreur_curseur_1=="oui" or erreur_curseur_2=="oui":label_alerte_curseurs.configure(text="\u26A0 Saisissez un nombre dans les champs en rouge.",fg="red")
    elif erreur_curseur_1!="oui" and erreur_curseur_2=="vide" or erreur_curseur_1=="vide" and erreur_curseur_2!="oui":label_alerte_curseurs.configure(text="\u26A0 Veuillez remplir les champs relatifs aux curseurs.",fg="red")
    else:label_alerte_curseurs.configure(text="\u2714",fg="green")
    label_alerte_curseurs.place(x=bouton_valider_curseurs.winfo_reqwidth()+10,y=largeur_fenetre-bouton_valider_curseurs.winfo_reqheight()/2-label_alerte_curseurs.winfo_reqheight()/2)

def valider_curseurs():
    global fenetre_ouverte,curseur_1,valeur_curseur_1,curseur_2,valeur_curseur_2
    try:curseur_1.remove(),curseur_2.remove()
    except:pass
    if decision_curseurs.get()==False or label_alerte_curseurs["text"]!="\u2714":valeur_curseur_1,valeur_curseur_2="",""
    if decision_curseurs.get()==True and label_alerte_curseurs["text"]=="\u2714":
        valeur_curseur_1,valeur_curseur_2=variable_curseur_1.get(),variable_curseur_2.get()
        curseur_1=ax.axvline(x=variable_curseur_1.get(),color="blue",linestyle="-")
        curseur_2=ax.axvline(x=variable_curseur_2.get(),color="red",linestyle="-")
    ax.figure.canvas.draw()
    try:fenetre.destroy()
    except:pass
    fenetre_ouverte="non"

def REPRESENTATION_graphe():
    global fenetre_ouverte,fig,ax,valeur_curseur_1,valeur_curseur_2
    fenetre_ouverte,valeur_curseur_1,valeur_curseur_2="non","",""

    x=[1,300,900,1200,1800]
    y=[1,2,3,4,5]

    # Construction fenêtres Matplotlib
    fig,ax=plt.subplots()

    axBtn=plt.axes([0.0,0.0,0.1,0.05])
    Btn=Button(axBtn,label="Curseurs",color="orange",hovercolor="yellow")
    Btn.on_clicked(gestion_curseurs)

    # Représentation spectrale
    ax.scatter(x,y,s=5,c="red")

    plt.show(block=True)

REPRESENTATION_graphe()


How can I resolve these issues?

X=int(variable_curseur_1.get())

I got a str, I forgot to convert into a int variable
